# Once User linked to record, the user cannot be changed (validation rule)

Tags: validation

I created a validation rule, which should trigger, when someone tries to update the User field on my record. It should be possible to update other fields on that record though.
I created this validation rule:

`NOT(ISBLANK( PRIORVALUE(User__c) )`

However, it does not seem to work properly because it is also triggered when I want to update any other field on the record.

Answer (score 0):

So that rule is saying, "if there was a value in User__c before this change, don't allow the record to be saved." You want to add an additional criterion that checks if the user is trying to change the `User__c` field:

`NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(User__c)) && ISCHANGED(User__c)`

This will allow entering a value in `User__c` if it was previously blank, but not changing it.